# Validity of 紅葉が出来る?

Tags: words, usage

Based off my understanding of できる in this context, it is used to describe something as coming to be. Would saying 紅葉ができる be a natural way of saying that the red leaves of autumn have come to be (i.e. the leaves have turned red)?

The full sentence of this context is as below.

> 紅葉が出来て、カナダは美しくなっています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

紅葉ができて doesn't sound natural. I think [紅葉]{こうよう}する is what you're looking for. For example:

> [木々]{きぎ}が[紅葉]{こうよう}して、カナダは今美しいです。

Or you could use 紅葉で (Lit. with / because of the red leaves)

> 紅葉で、今カナダは美しいです。

Comment: By the way, the only chance I think I could hear 紅葉ができる is in some science TV program explains leaf reddening mechanism.